Automorphism Group of a Locally Compact Group is a Topological Group
Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group. I have heard that ${\rm Aut}(G)$, the set of all automorphisms of $G$ in the category of topological groups, form a topological group under the composition and the compact-open topology. Almost all relevant writings cited J. Braconnier's 1945 `Sur les groupes topologiques localement compacts'. Unfortunately I cannot read French, and it's too long, old and typewritten with smudged inks, so that I couldn't find where the result is...
Important Edit: I reviewed the paper that cited Braconnier, and found that Braconnier only gave a topology with another subbasis, which is often called the Braconnier topology. Hence I am not even sure if compact open topology makes ${\rm Aut}(G)$ into a topological group. Accordingly I edited my question at the end of this post.
I have managed to show that the composition is continuous, but couldn't quite show that the inversion is continuous. I think that it suffices to show that it is continuous only at the identity, since then near $\varphi_0\in{\rm Aut}(G)$, the inversion map $\varphi\mapsto\varphi^{-1}$ is decomposed into (left translation by $\varphi_0^{-1}$) $\circ$ inversion near ${\rm id}_G$ $\circ$ (right translation by $\varphi_0^{-1}$).
Hence it is reduced to show the following.

For any compact subset $K$ of an open set $U$, there are compact sets $K_1, K_2, \cdots, K_n$ and open sets $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$ with $K_i\subset U_i$ for $i=1, 2,\cdots, n$, so that whenever $\varphi\in{\rm Aut}(G)$ satisfies $\varphi(K_i)\subset U_i$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots, n$, we have $\varphi^{-1}(K)\subset U$ (or, equivalently, $K\subset\varphi(U)$).

I was noticed that in general, even for locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, ${\rm Homeo}(X)$ is not a topological group with composition and compact-open topology. Since I only used local compactness and Hausdorffness in the proof of continuity of composition, I think somehow I need to use some specialty of locally compact Hausdorff topological groups, or that we are restricted to not only homeomorphisms but also to group isomorphisms. But I could not manage to utilize them.
Thus my question is
(1) Is it true that compact-open topology makes ${\rm Aut}(G)$ into a topological group? If so, could you prove it, or make a reference to reliable source?
(2) If it's not true, is there any counterexample? Or, is there a source which says that this is unknown?

Theorem 2.16 of these lectures notes show that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is a topological group for the compact open topology if $X$ is locally connected.

@FrançoisGatine Thanks. However, I am interested in more general situations, since in particular I am interested in profinite groups (that may arise from number theory).

It's not much of a group-theoretic statement. If $X$ is a topological space, $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ is a topological group. Then if $X$ carries a structure such as a group law, then the automorphism group can be viewed as the stabilizer of the law for the natural continuous action of $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ (here, on the set of maps $X^2\to X$) and thus is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$.

Are you saying that ${\rm Homeo}(X)$ is topological group under the compact-open topology? I saw some writings that this is not always the case...

The answer to your question (a very good question) goes like this.

Let $G$ be a locally compact (Hausdorff) group, and
$\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ be the set of all topological automorphisms of
$G$. It is not always the case that a compact-open topology turns
$\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ into a topological group.

A counterexample was constructed by Braconnier in his thesis (1945).
A copy of this thesis is widely known and available,
the copy apparently not the most recent version of this thesis.
A paper by Braconnier with the same title as his thesis was published in 1948:
J. Math. Pures Appl., Series Nine, Volume 27, 1948, 1-85.
This paper is freely available and can be downloaded from here (print quality is excellent :) )
A counterexample can be found in the thesis in chapter 4, paragraph 1 or
in the paper on pages 57-58.
